# Automatic display of a calculated parameter in the legend of a graphic

Tags: plotting

I was struggling to find a way to display a value which I constantly change automatically on a graphic. In this case, I want to display
`y=-220.3981+1.0873\[CenterDot]x   R^2=0.9995`
Basically, I have some data points adjusted to a line (I know the function `NonlinearModelFit` is not the best, but this is only a simplified case of my study and I usually use more farfetched equations)

```
data = {{220, 19.416}, {225, 23.409}, {230, 29.4875}, {235, 35.511}};

Clear[n, m];

CorrelationModelLine = m*x + n;

Korrelierung = NonlinearModelFit[data, {CorrelationModelLine}, {m, n}, x];

FittedData = Table[{i, Korrelierung[i]}, {i, 220, 235, 1}];

Representation=ListPlot[{data,FittedData}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue}, PlotRange -> {{195, 247}, All}, 
  PlotLegends ->Placed[SwatchLegend[{"Median Feret's diameter", "Fitted model"}, 
     LegendMarkerSize -> 5, LegendMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", "\[FilledSquare]"}, 
     LegendLabel ->Placed["y=" Korrelierung["RSquared"] "   \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(R\), \(2\)]\)=" \
Korrelierung["BestFit"] "", Above], LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 15]], {0.3, 0.15}], 
  Joined -> {False, True}, PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledSquare]", "."}, PlotStyle -> {Black}, 
Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Thickness[0.003], AspectRatio -> 0.8, GridLines -> None, GridLinesStyle -> Automatic,
   FrameLabel -> {"Threshold [-]", "Median Ferret Diameter [\[Mu]m]"}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 25], ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
FrameTicks -> {{True, False}, {{220, 225, 230, 235}, False}}, PlotLabel -> Style[Framed["Streptomyces coelicolor"]]]
```

My problem is that I cannot correctly associate the part R^2= and y= to its corresponding values, the display just shows both parameters and its corresponding values disordered. Also, the equation appears between brackets, any idea how I can remove them? I have unsuccesfully tried with the command `Flatten`.

Thanks everyone

Comment: Use [`StringForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringForm.html) in `LegendLabel`, e.g., `LegendLabel -> Placed[StringForm[
 "``\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]``\n``\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]``", y, Korrelierung["RSquared"], Superscript[R, 2], Korrelierung["BestFit"]], Above]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = {{220, 19.416}, {225, 23.409}, {230, 29.4875}, {235, 35.511}};

Clear[n, m];

CorrelationModelLine = m*x + n;

Korrelierung = 
  NonlinearModelFit[data, {CorrelationModelLine}, {m, n}, x];

FittedData = Table[{i, Korrelierung[i]}, {i, 220, 235, 1}];

Representation = 
 ListPlot[{data, FittedData}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue}, 
  PlotRange -> {{195, 247}, All}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[SwatchLegend[{"Median Feret's diameter", "Fitted model"}, 
     LegendMarkerSize -> 5, 
     LegendMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", "\[FilledSquare]"}, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 15]], {0.3, 0.15}],
  Joined -> {False, True}, PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledSquare]", "."}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Thickness[0.003],
   AspectRatio -> 0.8, GridLines -> None, GridLinesStyle -> Automatic,
   FrameLabel -> {"Threshold [-]", "Median Ferret Diameter [\[Mu]m]"},
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 25], ImageSize -> Large, 
  Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{True, False}, {{220, 225, 230, 235}, False}}, 
  PlotLabel -> Style[Framed["Streptomyces coelicolor"]],
  Epilog -> Inset[Column[{
      Row[{Style["y=", 16, Black, Italic], 
        Style[ Korrelierung["RSquared"], 16, Black, Italic]}],
      Row[{Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(R\), \(2\)]\)=", 16, Black, 
         Italic], Style[Korrelierung["BestFit"], 16, Black, Italic]}]
      }], Scaled[{0.3, 0.27}]]
  ]
```

with the following effect:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you very much!!